# How can i get the marker instance outisde the callback (cordova-plugin-googlemaps )

Tags: cordova, maps

```
              map.addMarker({
            'position': GETcoord('33.8730011','35.5179532'),
             'icon': CARicon(),
             'rotation': 90,
          }, function(marker) {

        localStorage.setItem('MARKER1',marker.get("position"));


        var MYMARKER1 = marker;





      });
```

What i am looking for is to get the instance of marker and use it wherever i want to change the marker position for example

```
    // alert(marker);
    var result = [33.8836142,35.5303557];
    setTimeout(function(){ transition(result,MYMARKER1); }, 7000);
```

is that possible ?

just for reference i am using this cordova plugin 
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: See this [PR](https://github.com/normesta/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/README.md); might be useful.

Comment: I think it should declare the map variable on the top of the sheet